# Design issue with modeling an availability matrix

Tags: jpa, entity, relational-database, data-modeling, domain-model

I am trying to design a specific part of a domain model for a website.

The issue I have is representing a sort of **availability matrix with days of the week (`Day`) and time slots (`TimeSlot`)**.

Possible values for `Day` are:

- Monday
- Tuesday
- Wednesday
- ...

Possible values for `TimeSlot` are:

- Before school
- Morning
- Noon
- Afternoon
- After school
- Evening
- Nighttime

Currently, I have a JPA entity with the two above enums (`Day` and `TimeSlot`) as fields:

```
@Entity
public class DayToTimeSlot {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @NotNull(groups = { Default.class, Validation.AdvertisementCreation.class })
  @Enumerated
  private Day day;

  @NotNull(groups = { Default.class, Validation.AdvertisementCreation.class })
  @Enumerated
  private TimeSlot timeSlot;
}
```

I then populate a `DayToTimeSlot` reference table with all possible values/combinations.

And finally, I have an `Advertisement` entity that has a `@ManyToMany` `java.util.Set` of `DayToTimeSlot` instances as follows:

```
@ManyToMany
private Set<DayToTimeSlot> dayToTimeSlots;
```

This results in a `advertisement_day_to_time_slots` join table which **can grow very quickly**.

***Is there not a better way to model this availability matrix?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you have only 7Days * 7 TimeSlots = 49 entries in the `DayToTimeSlot` table and then you only reference them in the Advertisement table.

**To remain fully flexible** I don't see any better ways to model the availability matrix. But your problem seems to be the association table. I would put myself the following questions: **how quickly** does it grow? Will you reach 1million in the next 5 years? To search in such 1 million-entries table is not such a big problem.

Independently of your answer to the last question you could think of [caching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Caching) the `DayToTimeSlot` table.

Besides, if you really do not want to search `Advertisment` by `DayToTimeSlot`, you could save the associations as a String field in `Advertisment` and load them when the getter `getDayToTimeSlots()` is called. E.g. On save of the `Advertisment` you itrate through the whole set of DayToTimeSlot, ad build a string of form : `"MONDAY_BEFORE_SCHOOL, TUESDAY_NOON,..."` and save it. On loading of an `Advertisment` you process the string in order to create the Set. Of course, in this case you will delete the `@ManyToMany` reference.

But another **feasible solution** would be the following (if for every week day you have a single entry of `TimeSlot`):
If you want to search for `Advertisment` only by day, or if you don't mind writing a bit more complex queries, then you could to add 7 new fields: `mondayAvailability`, `tuesdayAvailability`, to the `Advertisment` entity, save the data there and get rid of the @ManyToMany relationship..

Comment: Your idea to cache the DayToTimeSlot table does make sense! I am going to do that. Now, can you please elaborate on the idea to save the associations as a String field?

Comment: Done. Also I hope you considered the last idea.

Comment: I am not sure I am getting the last idea... Where do the fields go?

Comment: They go to the Advertisment entity. That would work "if for every week day you have a single entry of TimeSlot".